# Opencv imshow is showing weird image

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, imshow

I am trying to use opencv to display image series which are captured continuously by gphoto in Ubuntu (to calibrate camera). However, i am getting an weird output that is mixed between the desired image and current window.

[Image1](https://ibb.co/Gtj3HDb)

Finding chessboard code

```
camera.Capture(image,true); // capture image from gphoto
while(successes<numBoards) // check if the number of boards meets
{
    cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

    if(found)
    {
        cornerSubPix(gray_image, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.01));
        drawChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners, found);
    }
    imshow("Camera", image.clone());
    imshow("Camera_gray", gray_image.clone());
    int key = waitKey(30);
    camera.Capture(image,true);
}
```

camera.Capture code

```
    void GphotoCapture::Capture(Mat &image, bool isToCalibrate){
    char    *data;
    unsigned long size;
    capture_to_memory(camera, context, (const char**)&data, &size);
    std::vector<unsigned char> ImVec(data, data + size);
    Mat ImMat;
    ImMat = imdecode(ImVec, 1); // convert data in memory to Mat
    image=ImMat ;
}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be at the `GphotoCapture` end. You can also use `cv::imwrite()` to debug the the images.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, I tried to use imwrite() and the image was fine. The issue seems be with imshow() only.

Comment: `cv::imshow()` is pretty basic in functionalities, like it also misses the support for alpha channel. But I personally never encountered any issues with RGB images.

Comment: I would try to change the last line of Capture from `image=ImMat ;` to `image=ImMat.clone()` or `ImMat.copyTo(image)`

Comment: @ZdaR: thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Sane_or_not Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it but not luck.